# (closed) Jenkins| ClearCase UCM Plugin states Cleartool not installed

Tags: jenkins, clearcase-ucm

The problem is that when I use the [ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin)  and choose UCM ClearCase in the Source-Code-Management Section the job does not build. Tried it on the master and a linux slave.

I always get the following Error Message:

```
ERROR: net.praqma.clearcase.exceptions.CleartoolNotInstalledException: Cleartool not installed
```

The ClearCase_Home is set in the system configurations and I also tried to overwrite it for the slave. Still no success.

What bothers me is that when I use the UCM ClearCase option from the normal [ClearCase Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) it finds the tool but does not build the project. It only creates a snapshot and nothing else.

Still I would prefer to use the UCM Plugin as the projects are managed as such.
I did not find anything useful on the Internet. In all other cases there are still problems with the plugin not working, but no one gets the above mentioned Error message.

I hope someone can help me.

**EDIT 1**: Output I get:

```
ERROR: net.praqma.clearcase.exceptions.CleartoolNotInstalledException: Cleartool not installed
[CCUCM] Post build steps done
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried to inject wit **EnvInject-Plugin** the environment variables for the slave and running `echo $PATH` in the build section shows me the correct Path with `clearcase/bin`   in it. But in the System Configuration of the Slave the **PATH** variable is wrong and does not even closely reflect the one when executed `echo $Path` in the shell on the slave. So I think this is the cause for the Error.

**Edit 2:** 
Now the slave works with an interactive shell (using *Launch slave via exec of command on master*)  and the `PATH`and all other environment variables are set correct. But I still get the same Error Message.

**Edit 3:** 
I'm using a workaround by manually entering the commands to build the projects. So this issue is no longer important as it also seems to only fail in my case.

Comment: So it is indeed a PATH issue, as I illustrated in my answer. That doesn't explain why the slave PATH is wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

The cause seems clear: ([`java/net/praqma/clearcase/cleartool/Cleartool.java#L53-L72`](https://github.com/Praqma/cool/blob/e577cb120a9cc33e9a3c273fe90061435a1822b5/src/main/java/net/praqma/clearcase/cleartool/Cleartool.java#L53-L72))

```java
private static CmdResult _run( String cmd, File dir, boolean merge, boolean ignore ) throws CommandLineException, AbnormalProcessTerminationException {
try {
  return cli.run( "cleartool " + cmd, dir, merge, ignore );
} catch( AbnormalProcessTerminationException e ) {  
/* Validate exit errors */
if( e.getMessage().contains( "cleartool: command not found" ) ) {
  throw new CleartoolNotInstalledException( "Cleartool not installed", e );
```

So, independently of the `ClearCase_Home` Jenkins settings, you need to double-check if the PATH (for the account running the Jenkins job) does contains `</path/to/clearcase/bin/>`, where `cleartool(.exe)` resides.

Comment: checked the Path variable and ClearCase is added. Also when I try to run it from Command Line on the master/slave the command is recognized.

Comment: @JuliaGleichweit then the account running `cleartool` in Jenkins has not the same path. Try, as a pre-step in your job, to display `%PATH%` and execute a simple `cleartool` command, just for testing.

Comment: dunno why I can't add a pre-step, but if I execute it with the UCM unchecked in SCM it finds the tool. So it seems to me that the Plugin somehow is not working properly.

Comment: @JuliaGleichweit still, make another job with the sole task of displaying `PATH` and calling `cleartool`, just to see if that works.

Comment: with a sole task it works perfectly. tool is recognized and `path/to/clearcase/bin` is also shown as included in the `PATH`

Comment: @JuliaGleichweit I see logs in https://github.com/Praqma/praqmajutils/blob/abd07ceab28d3f3b56efc7f98b469a7f68cbce62/src/main/java/net/praqma/util/execute/CommandLine.java#L90-L120 (which is the code called by `cli.run( "cleartool "`: do you see any log?

Comment: @JuliaGleichweit seems strange. no logs from the underlying component praqmautils. Maybe this is an issue to mention in https://github.com/Praqma/ClearCaseUCMPlugin/issues?

Comment: @JuliaGleichweit "Building remotely on Windows_Slave in workspace xxxxx": is it possible the issue is on the slave?

Comment: I tested everything on the slave. the sole task finished properly. don`t think the slave is the problem